# Fanatic/Enthusiast badges missing in Teams

Tags: support, badges, stack-overflow-for-teams, consecutive-days

I just noticed that I lost the only gold badge I had on two of my Teams: [Fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic). Fanatic and Enthusiast don't appear on the (Teams-specific) badge list (`https://stackoverflow.com/c/[TEAM NAME]/badges`). Is this a deliberate choice or a bug in the system?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These badges were intentionally removed from Teams, in addition to a few others. A full list:

- Critic
- Citizen Patrol
- Peer Pressure
- Enthusiast
- Fanatic

We wanted to remove badges that do not apply well to Teams or otherwise encourage behavior that isn't desired among the Teams product.

Specifically addressing the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges: we removed them due to the adverse effects to maintaining a healthy work/life balance. We have to keep in mind that many teams are run by companies as workspaces for their employees. These two badges require users to visit every single day over 30 and 100 days. That includes weekends, a time when most employees are not supposed to be working. That inherently means that, in order to earn the badge, employees must check-in to a work portal over every Saturday and Sunday which is not something we or the employers want to encourage.

We get not all teams are company-controlled and that this is not an issue to all. But disabling them for all of Teams is the far simpler solution than setting up a per-team setting for two badges or modifying the criteria for Teams only, both of which would be considerable effort.

Comment: That makes sense; I *would* have expected an announcement somewhere. I guess this answer can serve as such, it's not that important ...

Comment: Would the (important) aspect you have about weekends, Saturdays and Sundays be better addressed/more inclusive as generic rest days?

Comment: @glo, if it's any consolation you get a notification about receiving the badges that [remains in your inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6f9x.png). It would be great if it was a per-team setting, since not all teams are company owned.